# How did the crew of the Destiny get out of the time loop?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

In the *Stargate:Universe* episode "Time", a time loop is created when a solar flare disrupts the stargate connection to the planet being explored by the crew of the Destiny, creating a time loop back into the past.

Probably a good thing, because the planet is inhabited by viciously aggressive creatures that attack the exploration party at night, and at the same time everybody begins to come down with a disease picked up on a previous planet.

The episode goes through two loops, exploring the planet with everybody dying one way or another before the episode ends with Scott explaining the situation into a Kino in case it's found the next time around.

The plot is described  [here](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Time#Plot) but it only takes us as far as Scott's plea into the Kino (followed by a nasty end).

There is apparently a short segment somewhere that explains this but its canoniicity was said to be doubtful.

The next episode picks up with everybody alive and no mention of the time loop. How did they get out of it?

Comment: https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Time#Plot

Comment: @DoscoJones Contains the setup but not the resolution.

Comment: The resolution is implied directly by that plot description.  All the information needed to answer your plot question is in there.  This additional link [explains it well](https://www.gateworld.net/universe/s1/time/).

Comment: https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/New_Kind_of_Crazy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The episode is harder to follow than most.

Important to this episode is that the crew ran low on water in [S1E06 Water](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Water_(episode)). They got some from an [ice planet](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Hoth) (Eli names it Hoth for [obvious reasons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoth)), and the water contained a virus. The virus starts to take hold during this particular episode [S1E08 Time](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Time). Here's the breakdown of how this all played out

#### Loop 1

1. Destiny drops out of FTL
2. Crew dials the gate and goes to the planet. Eli and others use his Kino to record their experiences.
3. The crew starts to get sick. Thinking the disease came from this planet, they stay on the planet to prevent contagion on the ship
4. Creatures attack after nightfall and kill some of the crew. Matthew Scott is bitten but survives and appears to avoid getting sicker from the illness.
5. A solar flare prevents the gate from reconnecting to Destiny, looping the wormhole to the past. The crew does not know this, only that the gate is not connected to Destiny. Nicholas Rush goes through and dies in the past near the gate.
6. With the rest of the crew dead, Matthew Scott dials the gate and records one last message on the Kino in hopes that it connects to Destiny. He throws the Kino in where it loops back to the past.

#### Loop 2

1. Destiny drops out of FTL
2. Crew dials the gate and goes to the planet. They find the Kino from Loop 1
3. They return to Destiny and watch the events of Loop 1 (**episode starts here**)
4. As people fall sick on Destiny, they realize they've contracted the same disease.
5. Rush realizes the wormhole was affected by a solar flare and that's how the Kino went back in time
6. They realize the creatures that attacked the crew from Loop 1 have some curative property and go to the planet to obtain a creature
7. Several crew die from the disease
8. The crew on the planet is massacred by the creatures, except Matthew Scott
9. Scott records this on the Kino after the solar flare cuts him off. From [the transcript](https://www.gateworld.net/universe/s1/time/transcript/)

   > *On the planet, Matthew Scott, still on his knees in front of the now open Stargate, lifts up the Kino and stares into it.*
   > SCOTT: If you found this, it's because a solar flare interfered with Gate travel and I managed to send this Kino back in time.
   > There's a creature that-that lives on this planet - lots of them, actually - that could hold the key to saving you. In small doses their venom actually cures the disease, but be very careful. They're deadly, but they're also nocturnal.
   > They only come out at night. You get them during the day while they're asleep in their nests, and they're not far from the Gate.
   > Please believe me. You don't have much time. Act now, or you are all going to die.
10. Scott throws the Kino into the wormhole, where it arrives in the past

End of Loop 2 and the episode

#### Loop 3 ([webisode extra](https://youtu.be/vte7LMnYV10))

1. Destiny drops out of FTL
2. Crew dials the gate and goes to the planet. They find the Kino from both Loop 1 and Loop 2
3. They return to Destiny and watch the events on both Kinos
4. As people fall sick on Destiny, they realize they've contracted the same disease.
5. Seeing Scott's message, they go to the planet during the day. They obtain a creature while it is asleep and treat the illness. Nobody dies.